# Excel Sheet Column Names matching A,B,C

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have two excel sheet, Based on Column B, I want column header from Sheet 1.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this simple INDIRECT formula:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&B2&"1")`

Comment: Thanks Mate Juhasz, If i want to vlookup this in another sheet then?

Comment: Yes Mate Juhasz